# Pagination in Angular UI Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is the following code:

```
<pagination total-items="20" ng-model="2" items-per-page="5" data-boundary-links="true"></pagination>
```

I hoped that this code showed me 4 pages ( 20 / 5 = 4), but I got only 1 page in pagination. What's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you still see the issue if you use scope variables instead of static numbers? so `ng-model="page"` where `scope.page = 2;` in controller?

Comment: yes, I still see this issue

Comment: I also notice that the correct attribute is 'boundary-links'... if you remove the 'data-', does that help? so `<pagination total-items="20" ng-model="2" items-per-page="5" boundary-links="true"></pagination>`